# Find $f(z)=u+iv$ if $u=\frac{e^x( (x^2-y^2)\cos y+ 2xy\sin y)}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, analytic-functions, cauchy-riemann-equations

They ask me to find the analytic function $f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ if we know that
$$u(x,y)=\frac{e^x( (x^2-y^2)\cos y+ 2xy\sin y)}{(x^2+y^2)^2}.$$

Am I supposed to find $v(x,y)$ satisfying the Cauchy-Riemann conditions in cartesian coords.? Isn't it too cumbersome to integrate and differentiate $u$? I don't think polars make it easier since there'd be $\sin(r\sin\theta)$ type functions and a quotient...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's cumbersome, but not *too* cumbersome. On the other hand, it is a mistake to ask for *the* analytical function whose real part is the given function; there are infinitely many of them.

Here's a way of getting one of them. Take\begin{align}v(x,y)&=\int_0^y\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x,t)\,\mathrm dt\\&=\frac{e^x\left(\left(x^2-y^2\right) \sin (y)-2 x y \cos (y)\right)}{\left(x^2+y^2\right)^2}.\end{align}It is then clear that $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$. And a direct computation shows that $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=-\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$. So, you can take\begin{align}f(x+yi)&=u(x,y)+v(x,y)i\\&=\frac{e^x\left(\left(x^2-y^2\right)\cos(y)+2xy\sin(y)\right)}{\left(x^2+y^2\right)^2}+\frac{e^x\left(\left(x^2-y^2\right)\sin(y)-2xy\cos(y)\right)}{\left(x^2+y^2\right)^2}i\\&=\frac{e^x((x^2-y^2)e^{yi}-2xyie^{yi})}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\\&=\frac{e^{x+yi}(x-yi)^2}{(x+yi)^2(x-yi)^2}\\&=\frac{e^{x+yi}}{(x+yi)^2.}\end{align}In other words, you can take $f(z)=\dfrac{e^z}{z^2}$.

Comment: Thanks to you both. I noticed  $u$ being the real part of $e^z/z^2$ but didn't know how to get there.

Answer (score 2):

One method.  Substitute
$$
x = \frac{z+\overline{z}}{2},\qquad y=\frac{z-\overline{z}}{2i}
$$
into $u(x,y)$, then simplify the expression.  Result:
$$
\frac{e^z}{2z^2}+\frac{e^\overline{z}}{2\overline{z}^2} .
$$
Then do it backward, to conclude
$$
u(x,y) = \operatorname{Re}\;\frac{e^z}{z^2} .
$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(z), g(z)$,in short $f, g$, be two complex functions. Then we have
$$\Re(fg)=\Re(f)\Re(g)-\Im(f)\Im(g).$$
The OP's function
$$u(x,y)=\frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}
e^x\cos y -\left(-\frac{2xy}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\right)e^x\sin y.$$
is
$$u(x,y)=\Re(\tfrac1{z^2})\Re(e^z)-\Im(\tfrac1{z^2})\Im(e^z)=\Re(
\tfrac1{z^2}e^z).$$